# ActiveRecord connection requires reset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, console

An application in production mode is returning content as expected.  It is assumed it is connecting to the configured database.  The `database.yml` file is as follows

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  user: deploy
  password: 888xxx888xxx
  schema_search_path: public
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5
  timeout: 10000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: fort_development

  <<: *default
  database: fort_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: fort_production
```

However, when connecting to the database via the console, whether in development (where the db does not exist) or in production, the console is connecting to the wrong database.  It is also referencing a username which was removed from the database.yml file (and app subsequently restarted).

*note: at one time the string `myapp` was referenced in the yml file for the `schema_search_path` attribute, however it was a commented out line (There is no certainty as to whether it was ever activated.'*

```
> bundle exec rails c
irb(main):001:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config
=> {:adapter=>"postgresql", :user=>"deploy", :password=>"888xxx888xxx", :schema_search_path=>"public", :pool=>5, :timeout=>10000, :database=>"myapp", :username=>"deploy", :host=>"127.0.0.1"}
> bundle exec rails c production
irb(main):001:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config
=> {:adapter=>"postgresql", :user=>"deploy", :password=>"888xxx888xxx", :schema_search_path=>"public", :pool=>5, :timeout=>10000, :database=>"myapp", :username=>"deploy", :host=>"127.0.0.1"}
```

The console and the app are not in synch.  What can make the console work with different values and how can it be reset to work with the proper configuration data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this, there is another place where rake can take instructions for connecting via ActiveRecord.

```
.rbenv-vars
```

this file within the directory for the application was mistakenly set as:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://deploy:PASSWORD@127.0.0.1/myapp
```

Another potential sources of problems (not clear why as the files properly parses in yaml) is to have the database.yml file only reference the production environment

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: fort_production
  password: [...]
  pool: 5
  schema_search_path: public
  timeout: 10000
  user: deploy
```